# "Wrong Top statement declaration" when import scala.reflect.ClassTag

Tags: scala, apache-spark, serialization, closures

I'm learning Spark's closures and their serialization, and I wrote a demo as shown below. But got a prompting "Wrong Top statement declaration" when import scala.reflect.ClassTag.

```
package lulijun.scala.study.serialize

import java.io._
import java.nio.ByteBuffer

import org.apache.spark.serializer.{DeserializationStream, SerializationStream}
import org.apache.spark.util.{ByteBufferInputStream, ByteBufferOutputStream}

import scala.reflect.ClassTag


/**
  * Created by lulijun on 2017/10/23.
  */
public class JavaSerializerTest {


  def serialize[T: ClassTag](t: T): ByteBuffer = {
    val bos = new ByteBufferOutputStream()
    val out = serializeStream(bos)
    out.writeObject(t)
    out.close()
    bos.toByteBuffer
  }

  def deserialize[T: ClassTag](bytes: ByteBuffer, loader: ClassLoader): T = {
    val bis = new ByteBufferInputStream(bytes)
    val in = deserializeStream(bis, loader)
    in.readObject()
  }

  def serializeStream(s: OutputStream): SerializationStream = {
    new JavaSerializationStream(s, 1, true)
  }


  def deserializeStream(s: InputStream, loader: ClassLoader): DeserializationStream = {
    new JavaDeserializationStream(s, loader)
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems like "scala.reflect.ClassTag" can only be imported in a object, not a class.

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with `ClassTags`. Scala has no `public` modifier. If class is to be public, you don't add an modifier at all:

```
class JavaSerializerTest {
  ...
}
```

You also have number of other problems, like attempts to access private Spark members (`ByteBufferOutputStream`).